# How to add authorization header to a react download button?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, authentication

I have a button where the logged user can download a file which is stored in the database and is fetched by react from node js/express js. Without authentication I can easily do that by just an  tag. But with authentication I am struggling a lot.

React:

```
const handleDownload = async () => {
    const result = await fetch (process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL + `/files/download/${props.id}`, {
      headers: {'Authorization': auth.token}
    });

    const responseData = await result.json();
    return responseData;
  }

return (
  <button onClick={handleDownload}>Download File</button>
)
```

Express js:

```
router.get('/download/:fid', filesControllers.downloadFile);

const downloadFile = async (req, res, next) => {
  const fileId = req.params.fid;
  let filePost;
  try {
    filePost = await File.findById(fileId);
  } catch (err) {
    return next(new HttpError("Error", 500));
  }
  console.log(filePost.file);
  res.download(filePost.file);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

possible solutions:

- verify that your auth.token really contains the token (try a
  console.log for example)
- if you're using a bearer token do this: {'Authorization': "Bearer
  "+auth.token}

Comment: I added Bearer and not I'm getting this error: "VM179:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0"

Comment: this is probably a typo somewhere, check your code and as i suggested try to console.log what you're passing as Authorization to check if its right

Answer (score 0):

from backend side you will need to do some changes learn jwt authentication or anyother authentication technique for backend and make sure that it works with frontend

how this app will work is when user is not logged in and he clicks on download backend verifies the token and if token is invalid or doesnt exist it send the error through resopnse and frontend shows it on ui

Comment: So you are saying that I should check for the user on the backend? I don't think that's needed because I can download the file is I add the Authorization Header on PostMan. It works smooth there.

Comment: have you setitem to localstorage from react and getitem for checking if user is loged in or not

Comment: I'm using cookies. But I used to get this error with localStorage too.